# "cap aborted!" - Capistrano aborts Rails deploy while attempting to chown /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW/. with fileutils.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, capistrano3

I'm a complete noob to deploying Rails to a production environment, and am seeing Capistrano exit with the following error:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: *** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `chown': Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW/. (Errno::EPERM)
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `block in remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `open'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:93:in `cleanup'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:49:in `block in list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `each'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/utils.rb:53:in `select_passenger_instance'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/restart_app_command.rb:44:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/main.rb:75:in `run!'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/bin/passenger-config:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `load'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `<main>'
passenger-config stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: *** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `chown': Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW/. (Errno::EPERM)
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `block in remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `open'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:93:in `cleanup'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:49:in `block in list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `each'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/utils.rb:53:in `select_passenger_instance'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/restart_app_command.rb:44:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/main.rb:75:in `run!'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/bin/passenger-config:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `load'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `<main>'
passenger-config stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => passenger:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: *** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `chown': Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW/. (Errno::EPERM)
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:726:in `block in remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `open'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:720:in `remove_entry_secure'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:93:in `cleanup'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:49:in `block in list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `each'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:42:in `list'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/utils.rb:53:in `select_passenger_instance'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/restart_app_command.rb:44:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/config/main.rb:75:in `run!'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.7/bin/passenger-config:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `load'
        from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/passenger-config:23:in `<main>'
passenger-config stderr: Nothing written
[me@localhost rally_app]$
```

The issue seems to have something to do with Phusion Passenger's config and perhaps the deploy user's privileges, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:** The error appears to be that Passenger is creating files in /tmp/ as the root user, but then trying to clean/delete them as the 'deploy' user which is assumed by Passenger because 'deploy' owns environments.rb.

The /tmp/ dirs look like:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root     root       4096 May 20 14:15 passenger.Jy8mOoq/
4 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root     root       4096 May  5 07:14 passenger.jZAgQb1/
4 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root     root       4096 May  7 07:13 passenger.M9fxTPM/
4 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root     root       4096 May  6 13:12 passenger.RWBkftW/
```

I don't think it is a problem with Passenger; it seems more likely a problem with my 'deploy' user's privileges.  I set up the deploy user following the Capistrano instructions [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not experienced with Passenger, but from you backtrace it seems that your deploy user does not have permission to access /tmp/passenger.RWBkftW/. file.

Check out, under what user passenger runs, for example with

```
ps aux
```

command on your server.

Then you should grant access to passenger to your deploy user, or deploy app via user that runs passenger.

Comment: Passenger runs with whichever user owns environment.rb, in my case that is already the user 'deploy'.

Answer (score 3):

Passenger author here. It's pretty much as Stanislav said. But I guess Passenger shouldn't abort with an error upon encountering such a problem. It was only trying to cleanup stale directories. I'll make a change to make sure it can continue to operate.

EDIT: this has been implemented in [commit c957e9e1171](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/c957e9e117110735b50bbfecb1ee82600ac688b2).

Comment: Hi @Hongli, I upgraded to Passenger 5.0.8 restarted Apache and my app but I still get the exact same errors when deploying.  There's slight difference in line numbers referenced in the errors, and of course the path now points to /passenger-5.0.8/, but the errors are the same.

Comment: The change isn't in 5.0.8. It will be part of 5.0.9.

Comment: Is there any way to get these stale files cleaned out, or will they accumulate forever?

Comment: Running `passenger-status` on the server will clean them.

Comment: I hit a similar problem. Running `passenger-status`did not resolve the issue.  When I found that other applications on the server were not serving, then I rebooted the server and everything fell into its expected place.